# Azure AD Auth - log out of specific app/ only?

Tags: php, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Here's my logout code (using CakePHP).

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->clearTokens();
    $this->Authentication->logout();
    return $this->redirect('https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . 
         Configure::read('Azure.tenantId') . '/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=' 
         . urlencode('https://example.com/'));     
}
```

so the user hits "logout" in the app; it clears some session data; then redirects to Microsoft to log out properly and redirect back again.

this seems to work OK but it logs me out of everything - I was hoping to just log out of the specific application - I've substituted `tenantId` for `appId` but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your logout behavior is not consistent with the description in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#single-sign-out).

> When you redirect the user to the end_session_endpoint, the Microsoft
> identity platform clears the user's session from the browser. However,
> the user may still be signed in to other applications that use
> Microsoft accounts for authentication. To enable those applications to
> sign the user out simultaneously, the Microsoft identity platform
> sends an HTTP GET request to the registered LogoutUrl of all the
> applications that the user is currently signed in to.

In other words, just calling the `/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={0}` endpoint is not enough to log your users out of all Applications. You still need to set the `LogoutUrl` from the app registration portal and implement such a `LogoutUrl` in your application's code to support single sign-out in your application.

Make sure you remove the `LogoutUrl` part in your configuration and it won't log you out from everywhere.